# Calculate ACF manually

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following equation for calculating ACF, I don`t want to use the function ACF in r, but calculate it manually for the following data and then plot the results using ggplot2

```
data<-rweibull(168,2,3)
time<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2014-01-07  23:00"),by="hour")
df<-data.frame(time,data)
```

[image]

where k is the time lag and μ   is the mean of time series (  , Yt=1,2,….N). The ACF is calculated here for time series considering up to time lag of 100 hours. In my final output I want to have an vector with 100 values. In the equation I don`t know how to set the Yt+k part of the equation in R for 100 time lags. Any help would be appreciated.

For now I have the code but I don`t know how to set the code to get 100 Lag results in one vector.

```
x <- data - mean(data)
sum(x[1:99] * x[2:100]) / sum(x^2)# TIME LAG OF 100
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it manually? What did you try so far?

Comment: To make some  modifications to the function and then compare the results. To set the time lag Yt+k with different steps.

Comment: As a start you can have a look at `lag` function offered at `dplyr` package. You will (probably) have to loop over say 1:100 for the lag size

Comment: Have you inspected the source code for the `acf` function?

Comment: I want to loop over but I don`t know how to set the loop.

Comment: I just checked the source code for acf

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129052/acf-and-pacf-formula

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this if you want ...

```
data<-rweibull(168,2,3)
time<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2014-01-07  23:00"),by="hour")
df<-data.frame(time,data)
x <- data - mean(data)

maxLag<-100
acfResults<- data.frame(k=c(1:maxLag), acf=NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


for (k in 1: maxLag) {
  N <-nrow(df)-k
  acf<- sum(x[1:N]*x[(1+k):(N+k)]) / sum(x^2)
  acfResults[k,1] <-k
  acfResults[k,2] <-acf
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but is it not clear how to store acf over k

Comment: above response updated per your comment. (but once you're done your testing, it would be an overwhelming preference to see you use the existing functions cited in above comments.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts